# Fatal Exception in thread

Tags: android

I got the error log

```
12-23 14:30:47.830: W/dalvikvm(13750): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught         exception (group=0x40a4f1f8)
    12-23 14:30:47.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13750): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-446
    12-23 14:30:47.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13750): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-23 14:30:47.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13750):    at      com.example.ctracker_bluetoothapp.IncomingData$2.run(IncomingData.java:189)
    `enter code here`12-23 14:30:47.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13750):   at `enter code here`java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     12-23 14:30:48.280: D/dalvikvm(13750): GC_CONCURRENT freed 113K, 4% free 6819K/7047K,    paused 3ms+6ms
    12-23 14:30:49.240: D/OpenGLRenderer(13750): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    12-23 14:30:49.810: D/OpenGLRenderer(13750): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    12-23 14:30:50.370: D/OpenGLRenderer(13750): Flushing caches (mode 1)
    12-23 14:32:14.770: I/Process(13750): Sending signal. PID: 13750 SIG: 9
```

I have this code

```
package com.example.ctracker_bluetoothapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.widget.*;






import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.*;

public class IncomingData extends Activity
{

  volatile boolean stopWorker;
  Thread workerThread;
  byte[] readBuffer;
  int readBufferPosition;
  Handler handler=new Handler();
  InputStream mmInStream;
  OutputStream mmOutStream;

  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

  Button btnCancel;

  TextView systemId1;
  TextView opMode1;
  TextView systemId;
  TextView opMode;

  EditText Ups1;
  EditText Mode1;
  TextView Ups;
  TextView Mode;


  EditText Hybrid1;
  EditText PHC1;
  TextView Hybrid;
  TextView PHC;


  EditText GridCharging1;
  EditText SolarCharging1;
  TextView GridCharging;
  TextView SolarCharging;


  EditText APSS1;
  EditText TPSS1;
  TextView APSS;
  TextView TPSS;

  EditText BV1;
  EditText SV1;
  TextView BV;
  TextView SV;

  EditText Main1;
  EditText Load1;
  TextView Main;
  TextView Load;

  EditText Trip1;
  EditText TCT1;
  TextView Trip;
  TextView TCT;

  EditText Now1;
  EditText TPSSValue1;
  TextView Now;
  TextView TPSSValue;

  EditText DC1;
  EditText LFBD1;
  TextView DC;
  TextView LFBD;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_data);

     mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
      btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

      systemId1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id. systemId1);
      opMode1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.opMode1);
      systemId=(TextView)findViewById(R.id. systemId);
      opMode=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.opMode);


      Ups1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id. Ups1);
      Mode1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Mode1);
      Ups=(TextView)findViewById(R.id. Ups);
     Mode=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Mode);

     Hybrid1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Hybrid1);
     PHC1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PHC1);
     Hybrid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Hybrid);
    PHC=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.PHC);

    GridCharging1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.GridCharging1);
    SolarCharging1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.SolarCharging1);
    GridCharging=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.GridCharging);
    SolarCharging=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SolarCharging);

    APSS1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.APSS1);
    TPSS1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TPSS1);
    APSS=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.APSS);
   TPSS=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TPSS);

   BV1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.BV1);
    SV1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.SV1);
    BV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.BV);
   SV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SV);


   Main1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Main1);
    Load1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Load1);
    Main=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Main);
   Load=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Load);

    Trip1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Trip1);
    TCT1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TCT1);
    Trip=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Trip);
    TCT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TCT);

    Now1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Now1);
    TPSSValue1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TPSSValue1);
    Now=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Now);
    TPSSValue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TPSSValue);

  DC1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.DCTime1);
  LFBD1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LFBD1);
  DC=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.DCTime);
  LFBD=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.LFBD);


       btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

        }
        });

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    boolean flag = intent.getBooleanExtra("CallSearchDevices", true);
    if (flag)
    {
        try{
        beginListenForData();
        }catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
}
public void     beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final byte delimiter = 126; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character


    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
           {
                try 
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new   String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");

                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {

                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        try{
                                            String[] values=data.split(",");

                                            systemId1.setText(values[0].substring(1));
                                            opMode1.setText(values[1]);

                                            Ups1.setText(values[2]);
                                            Mode1.setText(values[3]);
                                            Hybrid1.setText(values[4]);
                                            PHC1.setText(values[5]);

                                            GridCharging1.setText(values[6]);
                                            SolarCharging1.setText(values[7]);

                                            APSS1.setText(values[8]);
                                            TPSS1.setText(values[9]);

                                            BV1.setText(values[10]);
                                            SV1.setText(values[11]);

                                            Main1.setText(values[12]);
                                            Load1.setText(values[13]);

                                            Trip1.setText(values[14]);
                                            TCT1.setText(values[15]);

                                            Now1.setText(values[16]);
                                            TPSSValue1.setText(values[17]);

                                            DC1.setText(values[18]);
                                            LFBD1.setText(values[19]);

                                            }catch(Exception e){}


                                    }//rum method
                                });//handler

                            }//if
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }///for loop
                    }//outer if
                } //try
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
           }//while
        }//outer run
    });

    workerThread.start();


}//End of function beginListenForData


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.incoming_data, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I get this when i try to run the function beginListenForData()

Comment: Where you are initializing **mmInStream** ??

Comment: what you have at line 189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `InputStream mmInStream` is null. You have not initialized it. So, it is throwing `NullPointerException` in the line `int bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available();`  when you run the function `beginListenForData();`. So, initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

`mmInStream` is Null as it is not initialized anywhere (Line 189).

Hint: you can know the line causing the problem from the error trace

```
12-23 14:30:47.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13750):    at      com.example.ctracker_bluetoothapp.IncomingData$2.run(IncomingData.java:**189**)
```